# how can i use django comment_set.all

Tags: python, django, model, comments

**My problem**

Make comment model, and form for Django

Use {% for i in post.comment_set.all %}

no change html

Information saved in the comment form does not appear

how can i fix it?

**MY top_detail.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'create_comment' post.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ comment_form }}
        <input type="submit">
        {% for i in post.comment_set.all %}
        <p>comment: {{ i.subject }}</p>
        <p>time: {{ i.created_at }}</p>
        <hr>
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
```

**MY models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Top(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=30)
    product_price = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=30)
    product_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="images")
    product_explain = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, )

class Question(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Top, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=150)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

**MY urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views
from .views import PostList

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('home/top', PostList.as_view(), name='top'),
    path('home/top/<int:pk>/', views.top_detail, name='top_detail'),
    path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='main/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('create_comment/<int:post_id>', views.create_comment, name='create_comment'),
]
```

**My views.py**

```
def top_detail(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Top, pk=pk)
    post_list = Top.objects.get(pk=pk)
    comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'main/top_detail.html', {'post':post, 'post_list':post_list,'comment_form':comment_form})

def create_comment(request, post_id):
    filled_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if filled_form.is_valid():
        form = filled_form.save(commit=False)
        form.post = Top.objects.get(id=post_id)
        form.save()

    return redirect('top_detail',post_id)
```

**MY forms.py**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question

        fields = ('subject',)
```

**Should the pk parts of top_detail and create_comment (request, post_id) in VIEWS.py be the same?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing names. If you name something `Question`, don't call it by `Comment`. Same thing with `Post` and `Top`. It matters for your code.

For now, you have to use:

```
{{ post.question_set.all }}
```

But if I were you I would change naming, because it seems even you don't understand how it works :)

Like:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

then in template:

{{ post.comment_set.all }}
```

Comment: Why write a Comment rather than a comment?  Excuse me, is there any documentation I can refer to? thank you NixonSparrow!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It's not about documentation, it's about consequence in naming. You named an object model `Question` but you refer it to it `comment` later. It's just confusing even for author later :)